# Share named POSIX semaphores

Tags: c, posix, semaphore

I have issues understanding how to share a POSIX semaphore among multiple     processes. I am trying to do the following:
1. The producer initializes a semaphore
2. The producer posts 10 tokens to the semaphore and sleeps 1 second before       doing so
3. The consumer gets a token from the semaphore
When I start my producer, a segmentation fault (core dumped) occurs. Furthermore I am not sure, if my way of sharing the named semaphore is correct.
Producer:

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define SEM_NAME "/mutex"

int main () {
    sem_t* sem = sem_open(SEM_NAME,O_CREAT,0644,0);
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        sleep(1);
        sem_post(sem);
        printf("Token was posted! \n");
    }   
    sem_close(sem);
    sem_unlink(SEM_NAME);
}
```

Consumer:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <fcntl.h>    

int main () {
    sem_t *mutex = sem_open("/mutex",O_CREAT);
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        sem_wait(mutex);
        printf("One Token was consumed! %d",(int) getpid());
    }
    sem_close(mutex);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your consumer wait :

```
sem_wait(mutex);
```

and flush each print (if not prints may all be flushed at the end):

```
print("One token consumed\n");
```

Also; please take care of returned value from open:

```
if (mutex==SEM_FAILED) exit(1);
```

and

```
if (sem==SEM_FAILED) exit(1);
```

Comment: I forgot to change sem_post to sem_wait. But why does a segmentation fault occur? Furthermore may i test my program by executing producer in one shell and consumer in a different shell?

Comment: Can't see why a fault occurs. It doesn't when I tested it. And yes, you need to launch both concurrently (if not semaphore is of no interest).

Comment: The fault does not occur after I restart it, so thank you!